# how can i create a property containing a synchronized list which can updated by all threads in JMeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

i created this list on JSR223 PreProcessor. I access to this list by all the threads but the problem is that it is not synchronized

```
props.put("listOfTasks", new ArrayList());
```

someone has any idea how to do it ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `props` itself is [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which inherits from [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) which is synchronized by nature. More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)
2. What do you store there it's totally up to you, ArrayList per se is not synchronized so you might want to use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or call [Collections.synchronizedList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) function

It's quite hard to give a piece of advice without either seeing your code or background information like what you're trying to achieve, the safest solution from JMeter perspective is working with your list under [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) scope, it will allow to avoid any race conditions

Comment: thank you for your help, i solved the problem with : props.put("listOfTasks", (new ArrayList()).asSynchronized());